# Исчезает бургер меню при скроле в Safari

Tags: html, css, jquery, отладка, safari

Для практики создал небольшой сайт. При уменьшении экрана обычное меню превращается в выпадающее бургер меню. Все работает нормально, кроме iOS устройств.

Есть iPhone 6S, и при горизонтальной ориентации если открыть бургер меню и дотронутся к нему либо просто проскролить (изначально все элементы меню не видны) то оно исчезает и почему то не сразу срабатывает если нажать второй раз.

Выпадение сделал через JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.triggericon').click(function() {
   $('.nav ul li').slideToggle(500);
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 500 ){
      $('.nav ul li').removeAttr('style');
    }
  });
});
```

Само меню выглядит так :
HTML:

```
<nav class="nav" role="navigation">
   <a class="menu-trigger" href="#"><img class="triggericon" src="images/icon-menu.png"></a>
      <ul class="parent">
          <li class="linav"><a class="nav__link"href="#">Element1</a></li>
          <li class="linav"><a class="nav__link">Element2</a>
               <ul class="child">
                  <li class="linav"><a class="nav__link_child" href="#">Element2.1</a></li>
                  <li class="linav"><a class="nav__link_child" href="#">Element2.2</a></li>
               </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="linav"><a class="nav__link active" href="#">Element3</a></li>
          <li class="linav"><a class="nav__link" href="#">Element4</a></li>
          <li class="linav"><a class="nav__link" href="#">Element5</a></li>
      </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.nav{
    font-size: 20px ;
    text-transform:  uppercase;
}
.parent{
  display: flex;
}
.triggericon{
  display: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}
.nav__link, .nav__link_child{
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
  }
.nav__link:hover, .nav__link_child:hover{
  transform: scale(1.1);
  text-shadow: 1px 0 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav__link.active:after, .nav__link_child.active:after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position:absolute;
}
.nav__link.active, .nav__link_child.active{
  transform: scale(1.1);
  text-shadow: 1px 0 0;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Элементы выпадения меню, с которыми JQuery работает:

```
ul .child {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: #240158;
  padding: 3px 15px 5px 0;

}
.linav{
  list-style: none;

}

ul.parent > li{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Медиа запрос, в котором бургер меню появляется:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 770px),
only screen and (max-device-width: 770px){

.triggericon{
  display: block;
}


.nav{
  width: 50%;
}

.nav ul li{
  display: none;
}

.nav__link{
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.nav__link_child{
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  color:red;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.nav__link:hover, .nav__link_child:hover{
  border-bottom: 1px solid yellow;
}
.nav__link:hover, .nav__link_child:hover{
  transform: none;
  text-shadow: none;
}
.nav__link:hover, .nav__link_child:hover{
  color: yellow;
}
.nav__link.active, .nav__link_child.active{
  text-shadow: none;
}
.nav__link.active, .nav__link_child.active{
  color: yellow;
}
.nav__link.active:after, .nav__link_child.active:after{
  display: none;
}
.parent{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;

  background-color: #240158;
}
/*dropdown Navigation*/




ul .child {
  position: static;
  color: yellow;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Увидел один ответ что нужно ресайз убрать и там скинули следующий код, но т.к. с JQuery работаю только пару дней, не допер, что именно мне нужно сделать,а именно где коммент "// Тут функция которую нужно запустить при смене только ширины окна" :

```
var resized = false;
$(window).resize(function(event) {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    // Запрещаем выполнение скриптов при смене только высоты вьюпорта (фикс для скролла в IOS и Android >=v.5)
    if (resized == windowWidth) { return; }
    resized = windowWidth;

    // Тут функция которую нужно запустить при смене только ширины окна
});
```

Как попроще решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для показа и скрытия в Вашем примере Вы обращаетесь напрямую ко всем элементам списка, вместо того что бы обращаться только к родителю. Из за этого даже при простом копировании в code-snippet это дергалось и работало некорректно.

Попробуйте сделать так, и посмотреть изменилось ли поведение на нужном Вам устройстве:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".menu-trigger").on("click", function() {
    // используйте здесь дополнительные прверки
    // при каких условия данный клик будет срабатывать 
    // например, размер экрана, viewport'a, ориентация
    // или что то другое
    $(".parent").slideToggle(500)
  })
})
```

```css
.nav {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.triggericon {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}

.nav__link,
.nav__link_child {
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav__link:hover,
.nav__link_child:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  text-shadow: 1px 0 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav__link.active:after,
.nav__link_child.active:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
}

.nav__link.active,
.nav__link_child.active {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  text-shadow: 1px 0 0;
  color: #fff;
}

ul .child {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: #240158;
  padding: 3px 15px 5px 0;
}

.linav {
  list-style: none;
}

ul.parent>li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 770px),
only screen and (max-device-width: 770px) {
  .triggericon {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .nav__link {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
  }
  .nav__link_child {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    width: 100%;
    color: red;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
  }
  .nav__link:hover,
  .nav__link_child:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid yellow;
  }
  .nav__link:hover,
  .nav__link_child:hover {
    transform: none;
    text-shadow: none;
  }
  .nav__link:hover,
  .nav__link_child:hover {
    color: yellow;
  }
  .nav__link.active,
  .nav__link_child.active {
    text-shadow: none;
  }
  .nav__link.active,
  .nav__link_child.active {
    color: yellow;
  }
  .nav__link.active:after,
  .nav__link_child.active:after {
    display: none;
  }
  .parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #240158;
  }
  .parent.hide {
    display: none;
  }
  ul .child {
    position: static;
    color: yellow;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav" role="navigation">
  <a class="menu-trigger">Меню</a>
  <ul class="parent hide">
    <li class="linav"><a class="nav__link">Element1</a></li>
    <li class="linav"><a class="nav__link">Element2</a>
      <ul class="child">
        <li class="linav"><a class="nav__link_child">Element2.1</a></li>
        <li class="linav"><a class="nav__link_child">Element2.2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="linav"><a class="nav__link active">Element3</a></li>
    <li class="linav"><a class="nav__link">Element4</a></li>
    <li class="linav"><a class="nav__link">Element5</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Действительно, проблема исчезла)Спасибо большое!)